# Using macbook to connect to home desktop

Tags: ssh, remote, wan

I recently bought a macbook for university, as I am working on a laravel project I would like to leave my computer at home running the project and be able connect to it and to work on it at school with my mac, how would that be done?

Or is there any better alternative?

Comment: How much control do you have over your router & how much do you understand about networking? If the answer to either of those is "Not a lot" then get TeamViewer ;)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.